# Is it worth visiting Skellige for Gwent cards while grossly underleveled?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am currently level 10 and spending quite a bit of time finding **Gwent cards**. I think I've almost found all the available ones for Velen and have started to do more of the available quests - but I'm interested in whether it's feasible to go to Skellige and pay the (somewhat steep) price to get there, even though I'm under levelled and the quest still shows up with a skull on it.

I would not attempt to fight anything or complete quests there, purely try and find more Gwent cards and players.

If I am going to meet a painful end trying to do this, it doesn't seem worthwhile to attempt now - I could easily save the game and give it a try, but decided I'd tap into the knowledge of the stackexchange folk regardless - I don't even know for sure that more Gwent cards lay in wait there! I assume they do.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more cards available on Skellige - and you'll end up going there anyway.

If you are enjoying Gwent, and have no fear of running into the occassional over-level encounter, there are few downsides to travelling there to play more merchants / players.

Comment: Thanks - I went over and it's no real issue, you can just ride away from most peril on Roach.... found a few innkeepers who have extra cards and I've beaten 2 out of 3 of them, but not the guy who has the Geralt card and loads of hero cards, he's a pain >:-)

Comment: Ha! Nice. It's just a fantastic area to ride / sail around (plus Gwent, y'know).

Comment: The Celtic feel of the islands is actually really really nice, I love the music in the inns too - it's certainly different and very nice.

Answer (score -3):

the combat is so easy that I don't think you will have any problems with monsters less than 10+ levels above you (use tawny owl + quen), also a add a bleeding effect to your weapons because it scales with the monster's hp, not your level and you will kill them much faster,

also if you are there just for the cards chances are you wont have to fight much (I never bothered with the cards cause I don't like them, but chances are you will just be riding from village to village playing with blacksmiths or smth.)

on the other hand you will go there anyways in due time so why bother, the price for the ship doesnt matter because you will pay it all the same, and you don't really need gold for anything save some crafting mats if you are short